# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Screen_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, magento-1.6

I am developing a small custom module. While creating an admin screen under system->configuration, I am getting following error `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Screen_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 546`

I checked my code but nothing seems wrong. Below is the code of my `config.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Study_Screen>
            <version>0.1.0<version>
        </Study_Screen>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <screen>
                <class>Study_Screen_Model</class>
            </screen>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <screen>
                <class>Study_Screen_Helper</class>
            </screen>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <screen>
                <class>Study_Screen_Block</class>
            </screen>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <screen translate="title" module="screen">
                                            <title>Screen Settings</title>
                                        </screen>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Next I created Data.php in Helper folder. The code for Data.php is

```
 <?php
class Study_Screen_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
{
}
?>
```

and at last i created `system.xml` in etc folder. Code for system.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <screen translate="label" module="screen">
            <label>Screen</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        </screen>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Everything seems to be fine. I can't figure out the error. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First clear the cache.
Then check if the file `app/etc/modules/Study_Screen.xml` exists. I think it does, but check it to be sure.
I also see there is a space at the beginning of your `config.xml`: before `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. remove that (and maybe clear the cache again).

**[EDIT]**
I've test your code. Here is the problem:
in `config.xml` you have this line

```
<version>0.1.0<version>
```

The `version` tag is not closed. It should be

```
<version>0.1.0</version>
```

*Tip for the future:*
Always develop with error reporting set to `E_ALL` with `display_errors` `on` and mage developer mode set to true. If you do this you will get error messages on problems like this.

Comment: I tried it all, but its not working. I also tried putting the module in another copy of magento. Still the same error prevails

Comment: Also if i remove the code from system.xml its working fine. I am also getting the same error when browsing to user roles.

Comment: The problem is, that magento can not find your helper to translate the labels. If you remove `translate="label"` it should work already. The question is, how does magento try to initialize the helper. I thought `module="screen"` -> `helper('screen')` but obviosuly I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dexter. I've edited my answer. Even if my first answer didn't solve your problem I will leave it there because there are some good pointers.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. It's not a good idea to hide the errors like this. If the helper is not found but it's declared correctly in `config.xml` most probable means that the config file is not loaded. This will lead to other problems in the future if you hide the error. And you are not wrong: `module="screen"` turns into `helper('screen')` when translating the labels.

Comment: Marius I didn't want to hide errors, that's not how I think :-) I thought I'm wrong and just wanted to give a starting point to find the error :-) And if I'm correct, find the damn error and kill it!!! :D

Comment: @AdamMoss it is only a program if the helper is included before the first template is rendererd - therefore: YES. it is a problem, because the " " is output before maybe header() is called.