# Magento : Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Giftcards_Helper_Data' not found in …/app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento-1.7, php, configuration, helper

I have installed one module extension which throws an fatal error

> "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Giftcards_Helper_Data' not found in ..../app/Mage.php on line 546" in admin.

I have reffered this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/9191286/2919940 and this link as well https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7133/3693

But I have

```
<global>
<helpers>
        <giftcards>
            <class>Webtex_Giftcards_Helper</class>
        </giftcards>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

in my `config.xml` and I have this class

```
class Webtex_Giftcards_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data{
// my methods
}
```

declared at `/app/code/local/Webtex/Giftcards/Helper/Data.php` path.

I have disabled compiler and cleared cache by making empty `var/cache` directory.

I found everwhere that `config.xml` should have helper class define and Data.php should have declare that helper class.

But I have both of them in my case, what can be reason for this error ? I have tested that module on my fresh magento installation as well,

Magento version is 1.7.0.2

Please provide help for this error ?? If there's conflicts of class names how can we debug that ??

Thanks

Comment: Let me know if there is any additional information you need from my answer or if you have an update.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is common when referencing a missing helper.  In many cases the class name itself is malformed or your shortname referencing it is incorrect, which is why Magento is looking for it in the path `Mage_Giftcards_Helper_Data` (see example 1 below). For the following examples I have set up a module called `MyCompany_MyModule`.

These are just a few of the many ways you can go awry with defining helpers:

---

## Incorrect helper class alias:

I reference my helper as:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('mycompany');
```

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Mycompany_Helper_Data' not found
```

**What went wrong?**

My helper class alias is defined as `mymodule`:

```
<helpers>
    <mymodule>
        <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Helper</class>
    </mymodule>
</helpers>
```

Changing my shortcode to `Mage::helper('mymodule')` produced the desired result.

---

## Malformed class name

I reference my helper (correctly this time):

```
$helper = Mage::helper('mymodule');
```

I receive:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyCompany_MyModule_Helper_Data' not found
```

**What went wrong?**

My class definition was missing "_Data":

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Helper extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{


}
```

---

## Helper/Custom:

This is similar to what happens when you try to refer to a helper class within a file not named "Data.php".

I reference my helper as:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('custom');
```

My module helper path was defined as:

```
<helpers>
    <mymodule>
        <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Helper</class>
    </mymodule>
</helpers>
```

I have a class file in app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Helper/Custom.php

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Custom_Helper_Data' not found
```

**What went wrong?**

You need to specify other helper classes in a particular module as sub-paths to your module helper's shortname. This is similar to how blocks and models work - but at the topmost level there is no subfolder.

I fix this error by referencing my Custom.php helper class file as such:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('mymodule/custom');
```

Comment: Check Following link it might be also a problem of missing helper 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590164/magento-fatal-error-class-mage-giftcards-helper-data-not-found-in-app?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 4):

This only happen when you install extension with enable compiler 
Here is what you have to do

1 Step  app/etc/module/your module which you installed recently disable module

2 Step  Login to admin  /system/tools compiler disable compiler   Upload code again it will work fine then you can compile your code again

good luck

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the **Data.php** file present under your

**`codepool/extension_name/module_name/Helper/Data.php`**

2. If the Data.php present in the above mentioned directory open that file and copy the class name, Basically the class name having the Magento naming sense like

> packagename_modulename_foldername(Helper or Block) _
>   filename(Data.php)

```
<?php

class package_module_Helper_Data{

}
```

3. Move to magento root folder and make sure if the **package_module_Helper_Data.php** present in

`includes/src/`

4. If you are not see, create a php file with that name (which you got in error) under the **src** directory
5. Copy contents of Data.php and paste it in newly created file that's all. I'm sure it will help you
6. Still if you get error or magento showing nothing about the extension, just disable the compile mode under magento System->Tools->Compilation