# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Files_Helper_Data' not found in /public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, helper

I have been installing new modules, which by all accounts are functioning as they should.

I don't have much experience with Magento and have encountered the following error;

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Files_Helper_Data' not found in /public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547.
```

The line 547 states: self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);

This error arises when I click on product to go to the main product view. Up until that point everything works as should, search results etc. I've Goggled the error with no luck, I have tried things such as flushing the cache

Any guidance will be welcomed.

The full code where the error is;

```
/**
     * Retrieve helper object
     *
     * @param string $name the helper name
     * @return Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
     */
    public static function helper($name)
    {
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass); THIS IS LINE 547 ERROR
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }

    /**
```

It has not been explained how can I determine which module in Magento could be throwing the error or where those files could be located.

If someone could advise that would be great?

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: Have cleared the cache prior and after install of each module added.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a Helper class probably in a module called Something_Files. See if you can find that and create a Helper file without nothing but the class declaration. See [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/magento-fatal-error-class-mage-giftcards-helper-data-not-found-in-app-mag) for some more info.

Comment: It's also possible that @DanHoward has the class and the extension, but it's not enabled in `app/etc/modules` or it's not in allowed modules.

Comment: Thank you for the help.. How can I determine which module is causing the issue as the error code doesn't seem to make reference to one?

Comment: I'll go with a module called Something_Files since the Helper you are looking for is trying to find Mage_Files_Helper_Data

Comment: Where would be the best place to start looking for this. The odd thing is that the site and all extensions are working fine, just cant access the product detail page :(

Comment: I added some additional info if that would help further!

Comment: app/code/local and app/code/community is where you should look first.