# Helper Data not found - Can't access admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, module, error, fatal-error

Admin Panel only shows the following message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Sean_Adminmerchant_Helper_Data' not found in /home/makeyou/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

I deleted all files within:

```
app/code/local/Sean/AdminMerchant
```

Since I don't have access to the admin panel I cleared the cache by deleting my `var/cache` folder.

Then I went to includes/config.php and commented out both lines, then one line then the other (every possible combination) but still no luck it keeps complaining about,

> Fatal error: Class `'Mage_Sean_Adminmerchant_Helper_Data' not found in /home/makeyou/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546`

How can it still be bothered by this if it isnt there anymore?

On my remote host there is no trace is Adminmerchant anywhere!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see no mention of `app/etc/modules/Sean_Adminmerchant.xml` but if you're trying to remove the module to get back into the Admin, I'd make sure that that file is removed or disabled.

Otherwise, restore your module and then debug the issue. A good explanation of this problem is here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9981

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it finally thank god. @Tyler V I had the `Sean_Adminmerchant.xml`. I just always forget to include that when describing my problems.

So someone had a similar issue to me they deleted all the files just as I did clear the cache by deleting the var file.

The solution was I had to go to my `Mage.php` file and add

```
class Sean_Adminmerchant_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```