# "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Outgoing_Form_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php on line 547"

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, fatal-error, helper

I am getting error "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Outgoing_Form_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php on line 547" Even i removed module,layout file and module enabler file and i cleared cache also, but it is still displaying error.
[image]

Here is My helper file

```
<?php
class Bms_Outgoing_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Here is the config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bms_Outgoing>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Bms_Outgoing>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <outgoing>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Bms_Outgoing</module>
                    <frontName>outgoing</frontName>
                </args>
            </outgoing>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <outgoing>
                    <file>outgoing.xml</file>
                </outgoing>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <outgoing>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Bms_Outgoing</module>
                    <frontName>outgoing</frontName>
                </args>
            </outgoing>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <outgoing module="outgoing">
                <title>Outgoing Enquiry</title>
                <sort_order>72</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <items module="outgoing">
                        <title>Outgoing Calls List</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>outgoing/adminhtml_outgoing</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </outgoing>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Bms_Outgoing>
                            <title>Outgoing Module</title>
                            <sort_order>12</sort_order>
                        </Bms_Outgoing>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <outgoing>
                    <file>outgoing.xml</file>
                </outgoing>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <outgoing>
                <class>Bms_Outgoing_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>outgoing_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </outgoing>
            <outgoing_mysql4>
                <class>Bms_Outgoing_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <outgoing>
                        <table>outgoing_enquiry</table>
                    </outgoing>
                </entities>
            </outgoing_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <outgoing_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Bms_Outgoing</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </outgoing_setup>
            <outgoing_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </outgoing_write>
            <outgoing_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </outgoing_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <outgoing>
                <class>Bms_Outgoing_Block</class>
            </outgoing>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <outgoing>
                <class>Bms_Outgoing_Helper</class>
            </outgoing>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

This is the module enabler code

Bms_Outgoing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bms_Outgoing>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Bms_Outgoing>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/magento-fatal-error-class-mage-giftcards-helper-data-not-found-in-app-mag

Comment: what is your path of Helper define into config.xml file?

Comment: @Dhiren vasoya Bms/Outgoing/Helper/Data.php

Comment: @DhirenVasoya https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320795/magento-2-how-to-redirect-on-custom-phtml-file-from-a-module-within-module please check this

Comment: @Lokesh naik , i tried that link but all the helper class are fine still not working

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of Module Company folder name from bms to Bms.

And Module name from outgoing to Uutgoing.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try this steps :

```
1. Take the backup of the website.
2. Try to do the compilation from the admin.
3. Logout from the admin.
4. Login again from the admin and then check.
```

Comment: I done the compilation, even grid also won't showing, so i disabled compilation now grid is coming, but the grid edit form is giving fatal error.

Comment: share your config.xml file share how you declare the helper.

Comment: added config file